# Irreducibility of the polynomial $x^n+5x+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

(Now asked on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467368 )

I would like to determine whether the polynomial $x^n+5x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $n\ge 2$. I thought of considering $\bmod{2}$ so that we obtain a polynomial $x^n+x+1$. However the polynomial $x^n+x+1$ is not always irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790525/xn-x-1-reducible-in-mathbbf-2)) and I was stuck.

I also used matlab to check the irreducibility of such a polynomial. The result says for $2\le n\le 100$, $x^n+5x+3$ is always irreducible.

Can you help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried shifted eisentein?

Comment: You can also try one of the ideas given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454756/why-cant-xk5xk-13-be-factored?noredirect=1), for $X^n+5X^{n-1}+3$. It is very similar.

Comment: Also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164043/fx-xn5xn-13-cant-be-expressed-as-the-product-of-two-polynomials?noredirect=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The problems looks similar, but it seems that neither the answers in those posts nor shifted Eisenstein can be applied to this problem.

Comment: Standard criteria do not seem to apply to this one, if you don't find your answer here you might try your luck on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: It is easy to see that the polynomial is irreducible modulo five whenever $n$ is a power of two. While very far from a solution at least we know it to be irreducible for infinitely many choices of $n$ :-)